# how to dynamically choose row labels using tabulate in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are lists of integers.  It is created as follows:

```
table_dict_of_lists = {}
for label in return_dict_keys:
    temp_list = []
    for dict_list in stats_list_dict_list:
        temp_list.append(len(dict_list[label]))
    table_dict_of_lists[label] = temp_list
```

When I run the following:

```
for k, v in table_dict_of_lists.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

I get the following:

```
agentsGtX [566, 0, 0, 69, 134]
pure_user_dict [11818, 0, 0, 627, 1910]
inv_a_id_user_id [857, 0, 0, 73, 135]
user_email_id_dict [18005, 0, 0, 800, 2669]
ruurl_set [1288, 0, 0, 107, 247]
user_id_invite_dict [9772, 0, 0, 473, 1578]
pure_users_with_agents_dict [11060, 0, 0, 580, 1825]
user_id_email_dict [18066, 0, 0, 800, 2682]
```

This was all in the service of trying to dynamically print this data to table using `tabulate`.

I've got:

```
first_table = table_dict_of_lists
f.write(tabulate(first_table, headers = "keys"))
```

Needless to say, this puts the the keys as the column headers.  I've looked [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) but I don't see the answer.

How to I get the keys as label rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation never seems to suggest that row headers are supported in the library. Here's a possible workaround to at least get it to tabulate correctly:

```
f.write(tabulate(([k] + v for k, v in first_table.iteritems())))
```

Comment: Damn! you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks!  Why the bracket around the k?

Comment: Because otherwise it's only a string, and you can't concatenate it with v which is a list. You're welcome!