# How to add vertival headers in tabulate?

Tags: python, tabulate

So I made a table in tabulate and the output looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

So how do I do that ?

this is my code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

nums = {"Numbers": [0, 3.5, " ", -2, " "], "Seconds": [" ", " ", 24, " ", 3]}
print(
    tabulate(nums, tablefmt="grid", headers=nums.keys(), colalign=("center", "center"))
)
```

I will appreciate any help, thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to dynamically choose row labels using tabulate in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609716/how-to-dynamically-choose-row-labels-using-tabulate-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the following input:

```py
nums = [["Numbers", 0, 3.5, " ", -2, " "], ["Seconds", " ", " ", 24, " ", 3]]
```

and by removing the `headers=nums.keys()` argument ?

Edit: if your input is a dictionary as you shown, you can transform it into a list of lists as above:

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
nums = {"Numbers": [0, 3.5, " ", -2, " "], "Seconds": [" ", " ", 24, " ", 3]}
print(
    tabulate([[k]+nums[k] for k in nums], tablefmt="grid", colalign=("center", "center"))
)
```

Comment: isn't there a way to use dictonnaries ?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a dict as input. I can't test if the `colalign` parameter works though since I'm on Python 3.5 with tabulate 0.8.2

Answer (score 0):

To transform the dictionary in the

```
nums = [["Numbers", 0, 3.5, " ", -2, " "], ["Seconds", " ", " ", 24, " ", 3]]
```

you can use:

```
nums = {"Numbers": [0, 3.5, " ", -2, " "], "Seconds": [" ", " ", 24, " ", 3]}

col = len(nums["Numbers"])
rd = len(nums)
l = []
ln = []
for k, v in nums.items():
    l = l + [k]
    l = l + v
    ln = ln + [l]
    l = []

print(ln)
```